# Split lazy bytestring with another bytestring

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, bytestring

How can I split a **lazy** bytestring with another bytestring (e.g. `"\r\n"`)? I'm looking for a function like the following:

```
BSL.ByteString -> BSL.ByteString -> [BSL.ByteString]
```

I know about `breakSubstring` but that function is only available for strict bytestrings. I also saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398322/split-bytestring-on-a-bytestring-instead-of-a-word8-or-char), but the solution is using a strict bytestring.

Comment: Is converting to and from a strict bytestring, or copying the definition of `breakSubstring` (it uses `take` and `isPrefixOf` which are available for Lazy bytestrings) a suitable solution?

Comment: @user2407038 Converting to and from strict is not an option. I'm currently using a strict bytestring and trying to switch to a lazy bytestring because of memory usage. The [breakSubString](https://github.com/haskell/bytestring/blob/master/Data/ByteString.hs#L1350) function uses a number of `unsafeX` functions that are not available for lazy bytestrings. Maybe I can use the normal functions.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question: I have created a [pull request](https://github.com/haskell/bytestring/pull/129) that adds `breakSubstring` to `Data.ByteString.Lazy` (adapted from the strict version).

Until the pull request is merged, the following code can be used:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

module Lib (breakSubstring) where

import Data.Bits (finiteBitSize, shiftL, (.|.), (.&.))
import Data.Word (Word32)
import Prelude

import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BSL


breakSubstring
  :: BSL.ByteString
  -> BSL.ByteString
  -> (BSL.ByteString, BSL.ByteString)
breakSubstring pat =
  case lp of
    0 -> \src -> (BSL.empty, src)
    1 -> BSL.break (== BSL.head pat)
    _ -> if lp * 8 <= fromIntegral (finiteBitSize (0 :: Word))
             then shift
             else karpRabin
  where
    lp = BSL.length pat
    karpRabin :: BSL.ByteString -> (BSL.ByteString, BSL.ByteString)
    karpRabin src
        | BSL.length src < lp = (src, BSL.empty)
        | otherwise = search (rollingHash $ BSL.take lp src) lp
      where
        k           = 2891336453 :: Word32
        rollingHash = BSL.foldl' (\h b -> h * k + fromIntegral b) 0
        hp          = rollingHash pat
        m           = k ^ lp
        get = fromIntegral . BSL.index src
        search !hs !i
            | hp == hs && pat == BSL.take lp b = u
            | BSL.length src <= i              = (src, BSL.empty)
            | otherwise                        = search hs' (i + 1)
          where
            u@(_, b) = BSL.splitAt (i - lp) src
            hs' = hs * k +
                  get i -
                  m * get (i - lp)
    {-# INLINE karpRabin #-}

    shift :: BSL.ByteString -> (BSL.ByteString, BSL.ByteString)
    shift !src
        | BSL.length src < lp = (src, BSL.empty)
        | otherwise           = search (intoWord $ BSL.take lp src) lp
      where
        intoWord :: BSL.ByteString -> Word
        intoWord = BSL.foldl' (\w b -> (w `shiftL` 8) .|. fromIntegral b) 0
        wp   = intoWord pat
        mask = (1 `shiftL` fromIntegral (8 * lp)) - 1
        search !w !i
            | w == wp             = BSL.splitAt (i - lp) src
            | BSL.length src <= i = (src, BSL.empty)
            | otherwise           = search w' (i + 1)
          where
            b  = fromIntegral (BSL.index src i)
            w' = mask .&. ((w `shiftL` 8) .|. b)
    {-# INLINE shift #-}
```